# How to count files per folder?

Tags: bash

What I'm trying to do is to count json files in each folder.

My current attemp give total number of files, not per folder:

```
ls -d */ | xargs -I {} find {} -name "*.json" | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Command 1

The following command will recursively search all directories starting from the working directory. Directories containing at least one .json file will be listed with the number of json files in that directory.

```
find -type f -iname \*.json -exec dirname {} + | sort | uniq -c
```

This command assumes that all directories have single line names. It may fail in the rare case in which some directory's name contains a newline character. Some versions of `dirname`, `sort`, and `uniq` support null delimiters to work around this issue. Add `-z` to all of these commands.

#### Command 2

To also print the directories which do not contain any json files, you could use the following command. This command also handles newlines in directory names and allows to customize the output format (just modify the `echo` part).

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
count() { echo "$#"; }
for d in ./ **/; do
    echo "$(count "$d"*.json) $d"
done
```

#### Example

```
$ tree
.
├── dir1
│   ├── dir3
│   │   ├── a.json
│   │   ├── b.json
│   │   ├── c.json
│   │   └── dir5
│   │       └── alsonotjson
│   └── dir4
├── dir2
│   ├── lorem.json
│   └── yadda.txt
├── notajsonfile
└── somejsonfile.json

5 directories, 8 files
```

```
$ find -type f -iname \*.json -exec dirname {} + | sort | uniq -c
      1 .
      3 ./dir1/dir3
      1 ./dir2
```

```
$ shopt -s globstar nullglob; count() { echo "$#"; };
$ for d in ./ **/; do echo "$(count "$d"*.json) $d"; done
1 ./
0 dir1/
3 dir1/dir3/
0 dir1/dir3/dir5/
0 dir1/dir4/
1 dir2/
```

#### Don't Recurse

To only print the working directory as well as its non-recursive subdirectories, you can ...

- use `-maxdepth 2` for the first command.
- replace the globstar `**/` with a normal glob `*/` for the second command.

```
$ find -maxdepth 2 -type f -iname \*.json -exec dirname {} + | sort | uniq -c
  1 .
  1 ./dir2
```

```
$ shopt -s nullglob; count() { echo "$#"; };
$ for d in ./ */; do echo "$(count "$d"*.json) $d"; done
1 ./
0 dir1/
1 dir2/
```

Comment: `find -type f -iname \*.json -exec dirname {} + | sort | uniq -c` gives me an error `find: illegal option -- t`

1. `dirname` is a command or name of directory?
2. What is `+`, it's belongs to `exec` or  `dirname`?
3. Why we use `sort` if we then `uniq` anyway?

Comment: Seems this problem is from my side on MacOS `find . -type f -iname \*.json -exec dirname {} +` gives an error `usage: dirname path`, but on Ubuntu it works.

Comment: @mrgloom I cannot reproduce your error. My `find` version is `find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git` on Ubuntu 18.04. `dirname` is a command. `+` belongs to `find -exec` and means *"execute the command `dirname` for all arguments at once"* as opposed to `\;` which means *"for each match execute the command `dirname` again"*.

Comment: Also how to get only 1-st level count summary, i.e. in you example it will be `dir1`,`dir2`,`.`

Comment: @mrgloom Added a solution for `dir1` and `dir2` only. With more information in the question I could have posted the wanted solution right away.